# what will be the result of this imap command

Tags: imap

What will be the output of this command used in imap
"abc uid search 1:* UNSEEN UNDELETED".
 Whether It will give uid of those emails which are unseen and are not deleted or uid of email which are unseen and than uid of emails which are deleted.

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: i have to implement this command. i need to confirm the result.

Answer (score 1):

The proper result of that command is

```
abc bad [clientbug] 'unseen' is not a valid fetch item
```

In order: `abc` is the tag of the command, `bad` is right because the client could know ahead of time that its command is illegal, `[clientbug]` because the badness is due to a client bug, and the rest is just a human-readable error message.

Next time, try your commands with a couple of other IMAP servers. You'll soon get the hang of it.

Comment: on this link hint of the output is given .. it will give some uid

Comment: It is. You are looking for UID SEARCH.

Comment: Based on that other question, it seems possible that he's looking for some way to search, but someone has mutilated the server in question by chopping off UID SEARCH. Sometimes I feel that world peace would be a really good thing.

Comment: sorry sorry i am extremly sorry .. u r right its abc uid search 1:* UNSEEN UNDELETED ..sorry guys .. pls help

Comment: it will search UNSEEN MAIL which are not mark as deleted